# cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to store a list of multiple values from an object and store it in a dropdownlist by iterating through a loop.

```
ddlCountries.Items.AddRange((from country in countries
                               select new List<string> {
                               country.Name,
                               country.Slug,
                               country.Iso
                               })).ToList();
```

However I get this error message with the select keyword:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem[]'

Originally I tested to make sure it can retrieves values from the list using ListItem:

```
ddlCountries.Items.AddRange((from country in countries
                                     select new ListItem(country.Name, country.Slug))
                                     .ToArray<ListItem>());
```

This works perfectly fine, however I needed to retrieve an additional field (country.iso). I have searched the forums for a solution but I'm having a difficult time finding ways to solve this issue.  Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: What type `ddlCountries.Items` is? `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem[]`?

Comment: i think the code  : select new List<string> { country.Name,country.Slug, country.Iso} is wrong , you are trying to add object to List<string>

Comment: If so, then you are trying to add `IEnumerable<List<string>>` to an array of ListItem`.

Comment: @jophyjob I think you are right, it is supposed to be `select new ListItem { country.Name,country.Slug, country.Iso }` I guess.

Comment: @NikolaiSamteladze yes, ddlCountries.Items is a System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seeing as the `ListItem` class contains only `Text` and `Value`, you need some way of joining `country.Slug` and `country.Iso` into a single string value.

```
ddlCountries.Items.AddRange((from country in countries
                             select new ListItem(
                                 country.Name,
                                 country.Slug + "," + country.Iso))
                             .ToArray());
```

This will make it so that you are still generating a `ListItem[]` instead of a `List<List<string>>`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Anonymous Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)

```
var src = from country in countries.AsEnumerable()
          select 
              name = country.Name, 
              slug = country.Slug,
              iso = country.Name + " " + country.slug
ddlCountries.dataSource = src.AsQueryable();
ddlCountries.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

List expects only one String per item in the List.  Your new type has three fields.  You could instead try this:

```
    ddlCountries.Items.AddRange(
       ( from country in countries
         select new { country.Name, country.Slug, country.Iso } 
       ).ToList()
    );
```

But then, why do you need to create a List?  Have you tried binding the query directly as the datasource to your drop-down-list?  You could then define which field (Name for example) as the Visible field, and Slug/Iso as the Value Field - which is something that you would have to do even now.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can add an anonymous object to a locclection of ListItem objects.

Comment: This would of been ideal to have each field stored separately, but it gives error: Cannot initialize type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.

Comment: My bad.  I forgot that the AddRange expects an object[].  The correct approach would be to have the LINQ Query as the DataSource of the DropDownList control.  And map the Display Field and Value Field mapped correctly.